# What does 'after midnight on Wednesday' mean?

Tags: contemporary-english

> West Midlands Police said the devices were found outside an address in Coronation Road, Tipton, **just after midnight on Wednesday.**

> [MSN news : Bomb Squad Called](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/uknews/girl-hurt-and-bomb-squad-called-in-after-explosive-devices-found-outside-home/ar-BB15Ug5F?ocid=mailsignout)

It is now Wednesday. To me, 'midnight on Wednesday' means midnight tonight. And after 'midnight on Wednesday' it will be tomorrow - Thursday.

It actually took me a moment or two to work out that the Bomb Squad incident in Tipton (West Midlands, UK) happened early this morning.

I think the report should have said 'after midnight on Wednesday morning'.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: It's ambidextrous.

Comment: There is a semantic ambiguity, as in "squad called just after (midnight on Wed.)" versus "squad called (just after midnight (on Wed.))". The former sounds like it could be on Wed at 12:02 AM. You might be thinking of the latter. But I think there is no pragmatic ambiguity. The latter, being just after Wed's midnight, should also refer to Wed at 12:02 AM. I don't think Thu. is in view.

Comment: 'On Wednesday, just after midnight'. Though inherently ambiguous, this is the heavily default reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of style.

I can't determine what style MSN deliberately uses, but it may be that they have inherited the [Microsoft corporate style](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/a-z-word-list-term-collections/term-collections/date-time-terms), midnight belongs to the day it starts, or Wednesday as in the example.

> **midnight, noon**     Use noon and midnight. Don't use 12:00 noon and 12:00 midnight.
>
> Midnight is the beginning of the new day, not the end of the old one.

By comparison, the AP (Associated Press) [Style Guide](https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/noon-midnight), says this

> AP Style also notes that midnight is part of the day that is ending, not the one that is beginning.

Comment: Your answer appreciated. I have no idea why it was down-voted (since the voter did not tell us) so I have cancelled it with an up-vote.

Comment: I rarely worry about downvotes; I guess the answer could be more focused on just the MSN/Microsoft style, though I thought the comparison to "generic journalism" was of material interest.